# Call an external function from content script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Suppose I have `boo` function inside an external JavaScript file, from domain `http://localhost/file.js`:

file.js:

```
function boo() {
  return 1;
}
```

How can I call the `boo` function from content script in chrome extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to run a content script that creates and injects a `<script>` element that calls the page's `boo()` function.

Your content script should have something alone the lines of:

```
function runBoo() {
    var myBoo = document.createElement('script');
    myBoo.id = 'myBoo';  //helpful for removing the element later, not required to work
    myBoo.innerText = 'boo();'
    document.body.appendChild(myBoo); //if you plan on calling boo() multiple times, don't forget to delete the previously added myBoo elements
}

window.onload = function() {
//call runBoo() from content whenever you want to run the page's boo() function
   runBoo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts) from Mozilla:

> Content scripts can access the DOM of a page, of course, just like any
>   scripts that the page has loaded (page scripts). But content scripts
>   are insulated from page scripts:

- content scripts don't see any JavaScript objects added to the page by
  page scripts
- if a page script has redefined the behavior of some DOM object, the
  content script sees the original behavior.

**Reasons:**

1. it means that content scripts don't leak objects to web pages,
   potentially opening up security holes.
2. it means that content scripts can create objects without worrying
   about whether they might clash with objects added by page scripts.

**Update**

@Xan was right! thanks Xan.
if you need to interact with a function added by other page script, messaging between content script of your add-on and the page script is like this:

```
// main.js

var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var mod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require("sdk/self");

var pageUrl = self.data.url("page.html")

var pageMod = mod.PageMod({
  include: pageUrl,
  contentScript: "console.log(unsafeWindow.foo);"
})

tabs.open(pageUrl);
```

where foo is a variable added by a page script.

Comment: And yet, it's [perfectly possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script).

Comment: Content Scripts live in an isolated world by design, this is true, but since they have access to the DOM, they can inject code via a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Even the doc you quote says: _"Usually the insulation between content scripts and page scripts is what you want. But sometimes you might want to interact with page scripts: you might want to share objects between content scripts and page scripts or to send messages between them. If you need to do this, read about interacting with page scripts."_

Comment: @Xan the question in about how to call a function witch is injected by a page script, not how to inject or link a script.

Comment: Does executing `boo()` in the page context not constitute "calling"?

Comment: I suggest you read the other answer more carefully. I won't argue further.

Comment: `unsafeWindow` is Firefox-specific. The question is Chrome-specific.